# Unable to start activity. chronometer start button

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make my first application to calcaulate physical activities for me. At first, ive tried to make simple chronometer with start and stop button.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:id="@+id/Fit_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/fitapp_gray"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Current time"
            android:id="@+id/CurrentTime"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextClock
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Degree"
            android:id="@+id/degree"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="City"
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Duration"
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Chronometer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Calories"
            android:id="@+id/calories"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Steps"
            android:id="@+id/steps"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:background="@drawable/startbutton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:background="@drawable/stopbutton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and of course activity.java

```
final Chronometer chronometer =  (Chronometer)  findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
final ImageButton start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
final ImageButton stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);


start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chronometer.start();
        Toast.makeText(Activity_cal.this, "Chronometer Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
 stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    chronometer.stop();
    }
});
```

but everytime I try to run the app it force closes itself just before start.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton 

at com.example.dewewors.fitness.Activity_cal.onCreate(Activity_cal.java:31)
```

Fatal error is for Start button.
Could anybody kick me in right direction what else to do? Thanks

Comment: You don't include the layout XML for the `btnStart` so it's hard to say. My guess is that it is defined as a `Button` and not an `ImageButton`

Comment: @CoryCharlton btnStop is ImageButton, Try clean, build and run your project again is rare error

Comment: @g20 I know that's what the code says but the exception clearly states that it is not and without the layout there is no way to confirm.

Comment: Ive edited my question

Comment: yeap you should change the title of your question

Comment: Can you include the entire layout? The only thing I can think at this point is that you have a `Button` with the same id of `btnStart` somewhere else in the layout.

Comment: btw what is in Activity_cal.java line 31 ?

Comment: @g2o the identifier for start button
second line of .java above

Comment: provide your gradle please to check your imports

Comment: @Mina you mean build.gradle or console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Ive made fresh new project with all that parameters. Made new implement methods and it works now. Thanks for help I appreciate all the answers ;)

Comment: ok mate but before submit any question you must clean and build your project , looking for answer , finally post new question

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you're trying to cast to a widget from the support library something that is not. Change the imports, make both compatible.

Comment: The `AppCompatImageButton` extends `ImageButton` so the cast should be correct.

Comment: He was trying to cast a Button to a ImageButton. And the ImageButton is a   descendant of ImageView, not Button.

Comment: I know that's what the exception says but from the layout he posted `btnStart` was an `ImageButton` so something else was going on.

Answer (score -1):

it seem your are trying cast AppCompatButton Button in wrong way ImageButton

error in casting mean you try identify attribute in different type

Ex: in your xml

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:background="@drawable/startbutton"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

in java

```
              //  here is casting
Button mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
```

the issue that in xml you define it as `ImageButton` but in java but define it as `Button` so its crash and told you cant cast to different type

Comment: Where do I find AppCompatButton implements to correct it?